# Hide the emptiness in NewForm

Tags: newform

I used the code that added NewForm via "Content Editor", but form itself left a void, how to remove it, this is not presentable appearance?

```
$('nobr:contains("Test")').closest('tr').hide();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a NewForm page doesn't usually have the gap you have in your screen shot. Can you tell us what type of app/list/library you are using? Also I noticed the shadow so I take it Dialogs is set to Yes (found under advanced list settings) If you wanted you could set dialogs to 'no' and this visual gap wouldn't be seen.